# How to make the default satellite map in Google Earth Engine grayscale

Tags: google-earth-engine, basemap

I would like to get the result of the following photo in Google Earth Engine. QGIS screenshot with two levels: 1) Google satellite map with saturation -100, and with increased brightness and contrast. 2) LST with multiply blend mode.
[image]

So first make the Google satellite base map black and white (or without saturation) and second blend the Land Surface Temperature with the multiply mode. This is in order to create a good visualization of the phenomenon.

When I try to customize the map, in addition to not seeing the results of the map customization, I no longer see the layer with the LST.
Here my [code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/01d341d9e563fe9c7c825ec446a0815e):

```
//
// BASE MAP SETTING

// Define base map style.
var basemapStyle = [
   {stylers: [{saturation: -100}, {lightness: 45}]
  }
];

// Clear existing map.
ui.root.clear();

// Initiate new map object.
var map = ui.Map();

// Add custom map.
ui.root.add(map);

// Set basemap options.
map.setOptions('Satellite', {
    Satellite: basemapStyle
});

// Set the default map's cursor to a 'crosshair'.
map.style().set('cursor', 'crosshair');

// Set the center and zoom level of the new map.
map.setCenter(11.88,45.41, 12);


//
// IMPORT NORTHEN ITALIAN REGIONS

//var ROI = ee.FeatureCollection("projects/ee-robertoolorenzo/assets/po-valley-regions");
// Temporary ROI
var ROI = ee.FeatureCollection("FAO/GAUL_SIMPLIFIED_500m/2015/level2")
        .filter(ee.Filter.eq('ADM2_NAME', 'Padova'));
// Center Map
Map.centerObject(center, 12);


//
/////////// MASK CLOUDS FUNCTION \\\\\\\\\\\

// Function to Mask Clouds and Cloud Shadows in Landsat 8 Imagery
function cloudMask(image) {
  // Define cloud shadow and cloud bitmasks (Bits 3 and 5)
  var cloudShadowBitmask = (1 << 3);
  var cloudBitmask = (1 << 5);
  // Select the Quality Assessment (QA) band for pixel quality information
  var qa = image.select('QA_PIXEL');
  // Create a binary mask to identify clear conditions (both cloud and cloud shadow bits set to 0)
  var mask = qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudShadowBitmask).eq(0)
                .and(qa.bitwiseAnd(cloudBitmask).eq(0));
  // Update the original image, masking out cloud and cloud shadow-affected pixels
  return image.updateMask(mask);
}


//
/////////// SCALING FACTORS' FUNCTION \\\\\\\\\\\

// Scaling factors' function.
function applyScaleFactors(image) {
  var opticalBands = image.select('SR_B.').multiply(0.0000275).add(-0.2);
  var thermalBands = image.select('ST_B.*').multiply(0.00341802).add(149.0);
  return image.addBands(opticalBands, null, true)
              .addBands(thermalBands, null, true);
}


//
/////////// LST FUNCTION \\\\\\\\\\\

// Write a function that computes LST for an image and adds it as a band
function addLST(image) {
  var lst = image.select('ST_B10').subtract(273.15).rename('lst');
  return image.addBands(lst);
}


//
/////////// IMPORT AND FILTER L8 COLLETION \\\\\\\\\\\

// Landsat8 dataset
var dataset = ee.ImageCollection('LANDSAT/LC08/C02/T1_L2')
    .filter(ee.Filter.or(
            //ee.Filter.date('2020-06-01', '2020-08-31'),
            //ee.Filter.date('2021-06-01', '2021-08-31'),
            //ee.Filter.date('2022-06-01', '2022-08-31'),
            ee.Filter.date('2020-06-01', '2023-11-30'))
          )
    .filterBounds(ROI)
    .filter(ee.Filter.lt('CLOUD_COVER', 20))
    .map(applyScaleFactors)
    .map(cloudMask)
    .map(function(image){return image.clip(ROI)})
    .map(addLST);
    

//
/////////// REDUCING COLLECTION \\\\\\\\\\\

// Reducing dataset for LST median
var LSTreducer = dataset
    .select('lst')
    .filter(ee.Filter.date('2023-08-15','2023-08-16'))
    .median()
    .clip(ROI)


//
/////////// VISUALIZATION PARAMETERS \\\\\\\\\\\

// LSTreducer parameters
var LSTVis =  {
    opacity:1,
    bands:['lst'],
    min: 29,
    max: 49,
    palette:['040274', '040281', '0502a3', '0502b8', '0502ce', '0502e6',
    '0602ff', '235cb1', '307ef3', '269db1', '30c8e2', '32d3ef',
    '3be285', '3ff38f', '86e26f', '3ae237', 'b5e22e', 'd6e21f',
    'fff705', 'ffd611', 'ffb613', 'ff8b13', 'ff6e08', 'ff500d',
    'ff0000', 'de0101', 'c21301', 'a71001', '911003']};


//
/////////// ADD MAP \\\\\\\\\\\
Map.addLayer(LSTreducer, LSTVis, 'LST')
print(dataset)
print(LSTreducer)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change `Map.addLayer(LSTreducer, ..` to  `map.addLayer(LSTreducer, ..`, that's (`Map` -> `map`), to see the layer with the LST.

According to [`MapOptions.styles`](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference/map#MapOptions.styles) docs, `MapTypeStyle` options is applied only to labels and geometry, not to satellite basemap imagery.